How to handle notifications of a social media website with 1000 concurrent users
I have a social media website and I'm designing a notification service using Redis Pub/Sub and Socket IO.
I have created channels for each group and a group personal for each user.
Now each user will get connected to a group channel they are a part of and their own personal channel.
Now let's say there are 1000 concurrent users and each user is a part of at least 20 groups. Is this the best design to implement or I can change something here?
